# Failing to build node-re2 on a node:12.18.1-alpine docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

I try to get the node-re2 being build on latest node 12.18.1 lts alpine so that i can later copy the binary to the productive image. Unfortunately it fails to compile. What am I missing? Installing libc6-compat or gcompat with `RUN apk add --no-cache gcompat` or `RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat` does not help, even though the ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 file should be in the package.

My dockerfile is

```
FROM node:12.18.1-alpine as re2-builder

WORKDIR /opt

RUN apk add python make g++ \
    && npm install re2@1.15.0
```

When building I get this:

```
Writing to build/Release/re2.node ...

> re2@1.15.0 verify-build /opt/node_modules/re2
> node scripts/verify-build.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1188
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/node_modules/re2/build/Release/re2.node)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1188:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/node_modules/re2/re2.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! re2@1.15.0 verify-build: `node scripts/verify-build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the re2@1.15.0 verify-build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-19T21_07_53_335Z-debug.log
Building locally ...

> re2@1.15.0 rebuild /opt/node_modules/re2
> node-gyp rebuild
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Alpine uses [musl libc](https://musl.libc.org/) and its shared library loader name is `ld-musl-x86_64.so.1` which resides in `/lib` directory. `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is glibc shared library loader that's used in Ubuntu or other standard distros. There is compatibility layer package name `libc6-compat` try adding that.

```
apk add libc6-compat
```

Or try symlinking the original file

```
ln -s /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

That should solve.

```
Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
```